# adt plugin update failed

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

i am trying to update my ADT plugin from 18 to 20 but it is not working..

please help me and suggest .

i am getting these kind of errors

```
 - Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
 - HTTP Method Not Allowed: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse/content.xml
 - HttpClient connection error response code 405.
 - HTTP Method Not Allowed: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html/content.xml
 - HttpClient connection error response code 405.
```

Comment: +1 for asking. I was about to post a similar question but as soon as typed `ADT Bundle fails to update from v21.0.1 to v21.1.0` into the search box, your question appeared 1st and the answer by @faizanjehangir was right on target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using **https** protocol rather than just **http**, works for me some times

Comment: +1 for providing the right solution for a voodoo-like behavior of the update system. (you'd think that in this day & age, the update program will tell you what's really wrong, instead of showing you a red herring...)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, and I'm not sure about the root cause, but here's how I worked-around it. Not completely fixed but this allows me to compile and run, so I can continue development:

1. Download manual ADT Update, using this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
   (zip file link at the bottom)
2. In Eclipse, Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Archive (and select the downloaded zip)
   Only choose select the Developer Tools checkbox, leave NDK Plugins unchecked (having it checked gave me more errors)
3. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

try to change ADT location to this
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Help -> Install New Software -> Available Soft Sites -> ADT -> Edit

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Above post might answer the question. But  little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

due to descript in http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html :

Troubleshooting Installation
If you are having trouble downloading the ADT plugin after following the steps above, here are some suggestions:

If Eclipse can not find the remote update site containing the ADT plugin, try changing the remote site URL to use http, rather than https. That is, set the Location for the remote site to:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/